# NodeJS wait for function to finish

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can i wait for a function to complete, before executing another function in NodeJS?

Let's say thats my main function with db querys etc.

```
function main() {
    // Do some db querys here
    connection.query(query, function(err, rows) {
        if (err) throw err;
        for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            console.log('Got Row ' + i);
        }
    });
    // Do some other stuff here
    ...
}
```

And that's the function which is get called after the main() function above is completely finished.

```
function waitForMain() {
    console.log('Finally i was called!');
}
```

Is this possible with callbacks? Or are there other methods?

Comment: You can use async.series.

Comment: Your function should take a callback or return a promise - the latter is more modern.

Comment: If you don't want to use callback then you can use "Q" Module.  I have mongoDb Implementation on my github. https://github.com/vishal41190/assignment8/tree/withq

Comment: Can you show us code of query which you executing inside `main` function?

Comment: @Manwal i've added my query which get executed inside main. What i want is a callback if the db query got fully completed

Comment: @vishalpatel Q is really old better use something modern

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum  What is the modern way?

Comment: Bluebird on the server, native on the client @vishalpatel